# Turn old computer into WAN accessible file server?

Tags: mac-osx, network-share, server-message-block, wide-area-network, afp

I need to create a file server (possibly smb?) out of an old computer I have. This essentially needs to be a network drive that can be accessed over WAN by a Mac. The server can be Windows, Linux, or Mac based. I know that SMB, NFS, and even sometimes AFP can be quite slow to access, but I don't know which one is best for this use. I also need the server to be accessible using a common port to avoid being blocked by firewalls on the client side. What is the best way to configure this so that it is WAN accessible by a Mac, fast, secure, and not blocked by most firewalls?

Comment: You probably should be accessing this via a VPN like openvpn/etc.  Meaning you just need to open a VPN port through your firewall.  FS protocols are not easy to open through firewalls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might try looking into the Nas4Free project:
https://www.nas4free.org/

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest FreeNAS. Their newest release features a handy new Angular frontend in beta.

It also can host docker containers, VMs, and even act as an S3 backend.  Setting up network shares is possible on any computer, but if you're simply looking for an appliance to install and forget, FreeNAS is the way to go.

It's a FreeBSD base, though you'll never have to go into it if you don't want to. Additionally, there's OpenMediaVault, which is a Debian Linux based NAS software. The interface isn't quite as intuitive, but it's an option as well.